# How to verify my output coordinate of words match their position on HTML?

Tags: python, pixel, coordinate

Now I need to import paragraphs from txt files then display them in HTML files. My aim is to calculate the  accurate position((x,y) coordinates in pixels unit) of each word in HTML.

First I get words from txt files line by line.
Then I calculate the length of each word in each line in pixel unit.
So I can get the begin and end coordinate of each word in every line. 
Then I fill these words into a 600-pixel-width area in HTML.

In this way,I have got the (x,y)coordinate of each word in pixel unit.
Now I need to verify whether these coordinates match the position the words appear in HTML.

I have an idea that whether I can draw a rectangle for each word according to the word's begin and end coordinate on the HTML? In this way, if every word is in the rectangle, the calculation of the words' coordinate should be right. Is there anyone coming up with any idea how to achieve this? Or is there any better way?

Thanks a lot~

Comment: This'll work only if your font is monospaced (i.e. every character is exactly the same size). Why do you need to do this? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is flawed.
An easier way would be to find the word in the HTML, and use some CSS to change the style of its DOM element.

eg. Sample HTML.

```
<span> Banana </span>
<span> Apple </span>
<span> Cherry </span>
```

Now to highlight 'Cherry' with a rectangle, you do not need to find its coordinates in the page. Just find the DOM element and add a CSS class.

`<span class='black-border' > Cherry </span>`